# computing an operator norm exercise

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Let $X=\{x=(x_1,x_2,...):x_i\in\mathbb{R}$, $x_i=0$ for almost all $i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ with the norm $\|x\|=\sup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}|x_i|$. Let $S:X\to X$ be a linear operator defined by $Sx=(x_1+x_2+x_3+... ,x_2+x_3+x_4+...,x_3+x_4+..., ....)$. Compute the norm $\|S\|$.

I couldn't find $\sup_{x\in X-\{0\}}\frac{\|Sx\|}{\|x\|}$. Is it a specific number? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that it is bounded? You are adding arbitrarlly many terms.

Comment: Sorry, I confused the definition of bounded operator. I try to check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: For any positive integer $n$, if we set $x = (\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}_{n \ \text{ones}},0,0,\ldots) \in X$, then we have $Sx = (n,n-1,n-2,\ldots,2,1,0,0,0,\ldots)$. What is $\dfrac{\|Sx\|}{\|x\|}$ for this choice of $x$?

Based on this, is there an upper bound on $\dfrac{\|Sx\|}{\|x\|}$ over $x \in X \setminus\{0\}$?